# Настройка веб хука

Tags: bitbucket

Добрый день. Подскажите, если ветка на битбакете, как настроить веб хук, что бы при внесении изменений они автоматом переносились на сервер?

Comment: Про WebHook'и в BitBucket можно почитать здесь: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html и здесь: https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/06/24/the-new-bitbucket-webhooks/ Но я не совсем понял, что должно переносится? Если делать push в удаленный репозиторий (на сервер BitBucket), то изменения и так будут на сервере.

Comment: Я имею в виду проект лежит на bitbucket, а сам сайт на blabla.ru. Хочу, что бы при внесении изминений на битбакет обновлённые файлы пересылались на хостинг.

Comment: Такие задачи, как мне кажется, относятся к теме CI (непрерывной интеграции). Например: есть сервер git (BitBucket), есть сервер/сервис автосборки/тестирования (например, Jenkins), и есть рабочий сервер, где работает проект (сайт blabla.ru). При коммите в репозиторий в ветку master, Jenkins запускает сценарии автоматического тестирования (если они есть), если тесты прошли нормально, запускает процесс деплоя (установки/обновления кода на сервере).

Comment: Теоретически, на сервере (сайт, blabla.ru) можно разместить клиент git + набор sh-файлов, которые будут выполнять функции сервера интеграции (слушать web хуки и стягивать обновленные файлы из git)